# User profiles are getting corrupted, and the GPO to delete User Profiles is not working as intended

Tags: group-policy, user-accounts

I am working in a school were laptops are shared between students, and up to 60 kids can use the same laptop in a week's time. The first time we encountered any problems with this was when one class in particular came in with two students receiving an error:

[image]

At first, clearing out the user profiles (except the local Administrator, current logged in admin, and the Public profiles) in Regedit, and the C:\Users solved the issue.

After it kept reoccurring, we decided that employing the GPO "Delete user profiles older than a specified number of days on system restart" would be the way to go. We set it to any profiles older than 7 days.

Now, we have 2 devices from the same set come back with differing results: 1 has deleted *all* accounts, bar the last Admin to have logged in (the local Administrator account had been deleted) and the Public Folder. The Regedit records have an incomplete list of profiles, listing only:

- %systemroot%\System32\config\systemprofile
- %systemroot%\SystemProfiles\LocalService
- %systemroot%\SystemProfiles\NetworkService
- The last logged in Admin profile
- Several corrupted/empty profile entries

Any attempts to sign in using another profile states:

> The User Profile Service service failed the sign in.
>
> User profile cannot be loaded.

On another laptop, it however has done nothing - not even deleted a single account that was over 12 months old.

What could be causing these problems?